# How to have an app select the intent filter from the same app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am building multiple apps simultaneously. Each app requires to have the same imported library which I included in the Gradle like this:

```
compile project(':myimportedlibrary-release')
```

This library, in which I have absolutely no control over since its from a private source, contains an `Activity` which I open in my different apps using an implicit intent as required by the library. The problem is that if I have two or more of my apps on the same device, opening the library's `Activity` triggers an intent chooser with the `Activity` from all apps as choices. I could let the user select one by default, but it would be best if a certain app opening the library's `Activity` would just choose its own library. Would there be a way to limit the intent filtering to the current app?

I've seen how to restrict packages but then again, they all have the same. And I also cannot use `android:exported` since I do not have access to the library's `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an explicit Intent instead of an implicit one? It should resolve to the one that's in the requesting app. You already know you want to open a specific activity, so I don't see why you need the implicit Intent.

Comment: I don't know the name of the activity. All I got was a library, and a sample code to use it, which use an implicit `Intent`

Comment: Try using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager) to get the packageinfo, and use that information to target the specific class you want.

Comment: The package returned is __com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity__, which seems to be the class that opens the intent chooser

Comment: I succeeded in finding the class name with `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( myIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );` Then I could switch to an explicit intent.